# Renaming Service1SoapClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

Good day

I created an ASP.NET Web Service Application in C#, published it, and am hosting it on IIS. I then created a client program that will call the HelloWorld() method of the web service.

The code in the client looks as follows:

```
WebService.Service1SoapClient webProccessor = null;
EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/TestService/TestService.svc");
webProccessor  = new WebService.Service1SoapClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), endPoint);
webProccessor.HelloWorld();
```

How can I change "Service1SoapClient" to "TestServiceClient"? I assume this can be done in the Web Service, but I have no idea how.

In other words, I want the code in th client to look as follows:

```
WebService.TestServiceClient webProccessor = null;
EndpointAddress endPoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/TestService/TestService.svc");
webProccessor  = new WebService.TestServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), endPoint);
webProccessor.HelloWorld();
```

Comment: Remove web service from project referencies, republish service on IIS with new name, add reference again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I solved it:

1. Create a WCF service (will be hosted in IIS) instead of a normal Web Service
2. Create an Interface containing the HelloWorld() declaration
3. Create a class called 'TestServiceClient' that inherits ClientBase and the interface:

   public class TestServiceClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`<ITestInterface`>, ITestInterface

Inside that class create the methods:

```
public TestServiceClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
        base(binding, remoteAddress)
{
}
```

and

```
public string HelloWorld()
{
    return base.Channel.HelloWorld();
}
```

I am then able to call the service like I described in the question:

```
webProccessor  = new WebService.TestServiceClient(new BasicHttpBinding(), endPoint);
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the default name into another name, you have to change the name from the Service:

```
[WebService(Name = "TestService",Namespace = "yourNamespace")]
```

Comment: This only changes the service name though -- I end up with: `webProccessor  = new WebService.TestServiceSoapClient(new     BasicHttpBinding(), endPoint);`